# What does EKR(ROE) mean in capacitor markings?

Tags: capacitor

I have a [L4960](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00000075.pdf) regulator. In its datasheet on page 9 there is a typical application circuit. Under notes, it says C1, C6, C7: EKR(ROE). What does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ROE (Roederstein) was a German capacitor manufacturer, they made EKR-type capacitors. They are now owned by Vishay:

http://www.vishay.com/company/brands/roederstein/

It doesn't look as though the EKR devices are still available. If you contact ST they should be able to suggest an alternative device. Switchers can be fussy about things like capacitor types, you probably need to use devices with similar characteristics.

Answer (score 4):

Like Leon said, EKR devices were made by Roederstein. But I also found them at [Frolyt](http://www.frolyt.de/en/), a manufacturer I never heard of before, frankly.
[This datasheet](http://www.frolyt.de/x-ohne_VDA6.1-EKR_S1-5_10_97_1_.pdf) suggests that it's a series of low-impedance elcos, which indeed is what you want for SMPSs. Other than that the document doesn't mention what EKR means, materials-wise or process-wise.

Comment: I'll add my tidbit I found while searching about ROE EKx series and looking for replacement parts:
EK are standard, EKU are bipolar, EKR are low ESR and EKS are with smaller profile

Answer (score 4):

As stated, Mfg. is Roederstein (ROE), type is EKR.

There's a [replacement list](http://www.vishay.com/docs/28398/replace.pdf) saying that the type is replaced by the EKE series, [the data sheet of which is linked here.](http://www.vishay.com/docs/25008/25008.pdf)